# Django: triggering a change on template

Tags: django, templates, triggers

I have an event app written in Django / uwsgi / nginx.

A user makes a reservation, and it shows up in his "my reservations" page. For each event he can click on a check-in button, which checks him in.

The event organizer also has a "my events" page that lists who has registered for the event and whether or not they've checked in.

What I want is as follows,

1. The user clicks on "check-in"
2. The system records the check-in
3. When the event organizer is LOOKING at his "my events" page, just as the check-in happens, his page updates to show that a particular user has checked in.

How do I make this happen? How do I tell the organizer's "my events" template to update just after the user checks-in on his reservation?

Seems like I need something on the template that's "listening" to some kind of a database update (say the check-in table)? How would I do this? Is this even possible?

Thanks!!

Comment: Use websockets, via [django-channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: The easy way to do it is to constantly poll via javascript to some API endpoint. However, this creates a bunch of unnecessary requests. I would second Daniel's recommendation of using Channels.

Comment: Thank you both! Never knew such a thing existed.

Comment: Just curious: what are some python frameworks that "natively" support websockets? I'm guessing when Django came out it's not really as proliferate as it is today.